# Skylanders tower of time trouble

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

I brought the tower of time adventure pack for Skylanders Swap Force, and used it on my game. My friend didn't have the pack but wanted to play the extra level so I lent it to them, assuming it would be like previous adventure packs where you could use them as many times and on as many consoles as you want.

However, when he put it on his portal it didn't do anything, no error message, no cut scene, it didn't even register in his collection. I have looked online for a solution but I can't find anyone who has actually lent it to a friend, so I have no idea if the cheat of just lending figures to friends still works, or whether once the tower of time has registered on one console it can never be used again.

Has anyone lent it to someone else, and did it work on their console?